# How does `from <modname> import <attr>` maintain access to non-imported attributes in `modname`?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

According to the docs, `import <modname>` combines two operations:

1. Search for module named `modname`
2. If found, create and initialise a module object and bind it to name `modname` in the importing scope.

But I can't find a similar explanation for `from <modname> import <attr>`.

**Question**

Say `attr` is a function that refers to some other attributes of `modname` that were not imported. Why is it that when we only import `attr`, it is still has access to these other attributes even though they were not imported? Is it just through closures or is a module object created as in `import modname`?

Example

square.py:

```
num = 3

def squarenum():
    return num**2
```

test.py:

```
from square import squarenum

squarenum()   # prints 9 even though `num` wasn't imported
```

In the above example, `squarenum` can still access `num` even though `num` was not imported, why is this?

Comment: Is there a reason you would expect it to be otherwise? The globals available to a function during execution are the ones from the module in which something was defined; which module it's being referenced from is irrelevant.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no, I'd just like to understand why it works.

Comment: The code defining `num` still ran. `squarenum` has access to it, because to it, `num` is in its namespace. The only difference for you, the importer, is that you chose not to make `num` available for yourself.

Comment: @ArtieVandelay, oh true, I verified that by adding a `print(num)` to the module code. It executes when I run `from square import squarenum`. So the module is initialised and any references inside `squarenum` are looked up in the module's symbol table?

Comment: Pretty much. Importing a file with Python means you are essentially running that file. The entire namespace is built, and the last step is either binding that entire namespace to a module object using `import x`, or binding just one (or more) specific names to your current namespace using `from x import a, b, c`.

Answer (score 1):

the function object itself maintains a reference to the globals in which it is defined.  they are accessible at the `__globals__` attribute

```
$ cat t.py 
x = 1

def f():
    print(x)
```

```
>>> from t import f
>>> f.__globals__['x']
1
>>> f()
1
>>> # not that you should ever do this
>>> f.__globals__['x'] = 2
>>> f()
2
```

Comment: Thank you, so it's just due to lexical scoping, no module object is created as in `import <mod>`?

Comment: yes there is a module object -- it lives permanently in `sys.modules['modname']`

Comment: @user51462, ...to underline an implication of what Anthony just said, there's _just one_ module object per imported module; if five different modules do `import modname`, they all refer to the same instance in `sys.modules['modname']`.